# Share IDbConnection to keep transaction local

Tags: c#, generics, interface, transactionscope, idbconnection

Data Repository, which process a Data entity inherits from a generic interface and DAL layer is implemented as a generic class, which gets the generic interface as a Dependency injection. Following is the Design:

**Data Entity - Vehicle**

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public string Brand {get; set;}
}
```

**Generic Interface - IData**

```
public interface IData<T>
{
   IEnumerable<T> Select(IDictionary<string,object> parameters);

   int Update(IDictionary<string,object> parameters);

   int Delete(IDictionary<string,object> parameters);

   int insert(IDictionary<string,object> parameters);
}
```

**Vehicle Repository**

```
public class VehicleData : IData<Vehicle>
{
   IEnumerable<Vehicle> Select(IDictionary<string,object> parameters)
   {
      using(IDbConnection conn = (Fetch Connection))
      {
         // Select Operation
      } 
   }

   int Update(IDictionary<string,object> parameters)
    {
      using(IDbConnection conn = (Fetch Connection))
      {
         // Update Operation
      } 
   }

   int Delete(IDictionary<string,object> parameters)
    {
      using(IDbConnection conn = (Fetch Connection))
      {
         // Delete Operation
      } 
   }

   int insert(IDictionary<string,object> parameters)
    {
      using(IDbConnection conn = (Fetch Connection))
      {
         // Insert Operation
      } 
   }
}
```

**DAL Class implementation :**

```
public class DAL<T>
{
  public static IEnumerable<T> Select(IData<T> dataRepository, IDictionary<string,object> parameters)
   {
       return dataRepository.Select(parameters);
   }

// Implementation for Insert, Update and Delete
}
```

I execute the `VehicleData` using `DAL` from the calling class as follows.

```
IData<Vehicle> vehicleData = new VehicleData();

IDictionary<string,object> parameters = // Filled from client

DAL<Vehicle>.Select(vehicleData,parameters);
```

Issue that I face is, in each CRUD method, IDbConnection is created in the `Using` block, thus disposed in the end, as its in the local context, but there's scenario, where multiple DAL operations on various entities need to be part of single transaction context, if I continue in a similar way then transaction context opened will be promoted to distributed level, since multiple connection resources are opening, even when I can do them on same connection context as they are executed one by one. Issue remains:

1. How shall share the connection across multiple calls like `DAL<Vehicle>.Update, DAL<Driver>.Update and DAL<Truck>.Update`, so that transaction promotion from local to distributed can be avoided
2. Not sure, does opening and disposing a connection in a transaction context means another connection can be opened without promotion to distributed transaction, in my view this would not happen

Answer (score 1):

Are you using IoC container for Dependency injection? In IoC there are some lifestyles (per thread, per web request and etc.) For example, with castle windsor you can use [Scoped lifestyle](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/lifestyles.md). And your code will be like this:

Create connection (linq2db):

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<DataConnection>().UsingFactoryMethod(x => 
        CreateDataConnection()).LifestyleScoped(),
    Component.For<IData<Vehicle>>()
        .ImplementedBy<VehicleData>().LifestyleScoped()
);

private static DataConnection CreateDataConnection()
{
    return new DataConnection(new SqlServerDataProvider("", SqlServerVersion.v2008), 
        @"Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=DB1;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=pwd");
}
```

Do some db operations:

```
using (container.BeginScope())
{
    var db = container.Resolve<DataConnection>();
    db.BeginTransaction();
    container.Resolve<IData<Vehicle>>().Update(...);
    container.Resolve<IData<Vehicle>>().Update(...);
    container.Resolve<IData<Vehicle>>().Update(...);
    db.CommitTransaction();
}
```

Comment: This is not an exact solution for my problem statement, but it does provide me a clue to start having IDbConnection as a parameter and pass from the caller same connection, especially since I am keen about TransactionScope than IDbConnection, your solution just makes the Container context common for all calls, nonetheless thanks for a heads up